# yq filter with select from different map/list

Tags: yaml, yq

```
example_a:
  - key: sa01
    name: sa

match_a:
  sa_key: sa01
```

This one works:

```
yq '.example_a[] |select(.key == "sa01")'
```

Is it possible to make it work this way:

```
yq '.example_a[] |select(.key == .match_a.sa_key)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using a variable on the key:

```
yq '.match_a.sa_key as $key | .example_a[] |select(.key == $key)' i.yaml
```

So we save `.match_a.sa_key` as the var `$key`, so that we can use that in the `select()` directly

---

Output:

```yaml
key: sa01
name: sa
```